# Using NSDataDetector to just like Apple's Notes app

Tags: ios, swift, nsdatadetector

I'm trying to find several different data types including Dates, Addresses, Phone numbers, and Links.  I'm already able to find them but I want to be able to format them by underlining and changing their color.  This is my code so far.

```
func detectData() {
        let text = self.textView.text
        let types: NSTextCheckingType = .Date | .Address | .PhoneNumber | .Link
        var error: NSError?
        let detector = NSDataDetector(types: types.rawValue, error: &error)
        var dataMatches: NSArray = [detector!.matchesInString(text, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, (text as NSString).length))]

        for match in dataMatches {
```

I was thinking I should first get each result out of the loop then 
1) turn them into strings 2)format them.

First question.  How will I put my formatted string back into my UITextView at the same place?

Second question.  I'm thinking about creating a switch like so

```
switch match {
                case match == NSTextCheckingType.date
```

but now that I have a specific type of NSTextCheckingType, what do I have to do to make them have the functionality I want? (e.g. call a phone number, open up maps for an address, create a event for a date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what Notes does you just need to set the dataDetectorTypes property on your text view. That's all! No NSDataDetector involved.

Comment: Oh my...I guess NSDataDetector is for a more focused search/customization.  Thanks, easy fix :)